# Ubercart USPS error message

Tags: ubercart, usps

I have shipping quotes with USPS enabled, and I turned on debugging information so I can receive the request/response information:

```
API=RateV3&XML=
<RateV3Request USERID="(Hidden)">
<Package ID="0">
    <Service>ALL</Service>
    <ZipOrigination>90038</ZipOrigination>
    <ZipDestination>90024</ZipDestination>
    <Pounds>1</Pounds>
    <Ounces>0.0</Ounces>
    <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>
    <Size>REGULAR</Size>
    <Machinable>False</Machinable>
</Package>
</RateV3Request>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RateV3Response>
    <Package ID="0">
        <ZipOrigination>90038</ZipOrigination>
        <ZipDestination>90024</ZipDestination>
        <Pounds>1</Pounds>
        <Ounces>0.0</Ounces>
        <Size>REGULAR</Size>
        <Machinable>FALSE</Machinable>
        <Zone>1</Zone>
        <Postage CLASSID="23">
            <MailService>Express Mail Sunday/Holiday Guarantee</MailService>
            <Rate>27.50</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="25">
            <MailService>Express Mail Flat-Rate Envelope Sunday/Holiday Guarantee</MailService>
            <Rate>30.00</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="2">
            <MailService>Express Mail Hold For Pickup</MailService>
            <Rate>15.00</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="27">
            <MailService>Express Mail Flat-Rate Envelope Hold For Pickup</MailService>
            <Rate>17.50</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="3">
            <MailService>Express Mail</MailService>
            <Rate>15.00</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="13">
            <MailService>Express Mail Flat-Rate Envelope</MailService>
            <Rate>17.50</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="1">
            <MailService>Priority Mail</MailService>
            <Rate>4.95</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="16">
            <MailService>Priority Mail Flat-Rate Envelope</MailService>
            <Rate>4.95</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="28">
            <MailService>Priority Mail Small Flat-Rate Box</MailService>
            <Rate>4.95</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="17">
            <MailService>Priority Mail Regular/Medium Flat-Rate Boxes</MailService>
            <Rate>10.35</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="22">
            <MailService>Priority Mail Large Flat-Rate Box</MailService>
            <Rate>13.95</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="4">
            <MailService>Parcel Post</MailService>
            <Rate>4.90</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="5">
            <MailService>Bound Printed Matter</MailService>
            <Rate>2.33</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="6">
            <MailService>Media Mail</MailService>
            <Rate>2.38</Rate>
        </Postage>
        <Postage CLASSID="7">
            <MailService>Library Mail</MailService>
            <Rate>2.26</Rate>
        </Postage>
    </Package>
</RateV3Response>
```

It looks like the response is fine, but I'm not getting an actual shipping quote on my page after asking it to calculate. Instead I get the error "There were problems getting a shipping quote. Please verify the delivery and product information and try again. If this does not resolve the issue, please call in to complete your order."

If anyone has any information why it would still show an error, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure out a solution? I was getting a similar response and I was able to clear it up by selecting different shipping options. It seems in the usps shipping module the First Class Mail Parcel and the First Class Mail Flat options are set to values that don't correspond to shipping rates.

this is on a Drupal 6 site.